# Python - polymorphism in instance methods vs polymorphism in static methods

Tags: python, polymorphism, static-methods, instance-methods

What is the practical difference between instance methods and static methods, since these two codes return the same results? I understand that static methods do not operate on ‘self’ and do not have direct access to attributes, but how can I verify that instance methods are truly being overridden (are truly polymorphistic), while static methods are not?

```
class BaseClass:
    def instance_method(self):
        return "Instance method of base class"

    @staticmethod
    def static_method():
        return "Static method of base class"

class DerivedClass(BaseClass):
    def instance_method(self):
        return "Instance method of derived class"

    @staticmethod
    def static_method():
        return "Static method of derived class"

base_object = BaseClass()
derived_object = DerivedClass()

print(base_object.instance_method())  # Displays: "Instance method of base class"
print(derived_object.instance_method())  # Displays: "Instance method of derived class"

print(BaseClass.static_method())  # Displays: "Static method of base class"
print(DerivedClass.static_method())  # Displays: "Static method of derived class"

print(base_object.static_method())  # Displays: "Static method of base class"
print(derived_object.static_method())  # Displays: "Static method of derived class"
```

How can I check the truly polymorphism of instance methods? Maybe I understand wrong the whole concept of polymorphism?

Comment: So, it looks like static methods are overridden just like normal methods. Your test code seems to prove this.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I'm quite new to Python and Microsoft AI still convinces me that static methods aren't polymorphistic and that static_method in DerivedClass has nothing to do with static_method in BaseClass :D And that's why I asked more experienced people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like any programming language, you just need to write code in that language to determine what its behaviours are:

```py
class BaseClass:
    def instance_method(self):
        return "Instance method of base class"

    @staticmethod
    def static_method():
        return "Static method of base class"
    
    def normal_base_method(self):
        return self.static_method() + " called from normal_base_method"

class DerivedClass(BaseClass):
    def instance_method(self):
        return "Instance method of derived class"

    @staticmethod
    def static_method():
        return "Static method of derived class"

base_object = BaseClass()
derived_object = DerivedClass()

print(base_object.normal_base_method())
print(derived_object.normal_base_method())
```

Output:

```
Static method of base class called from normal_base_method
Static method of derived class called from normal_base_method
```

The above output shows that calling a method defined solely in the base class changes behaviour because the instance is of the derived class.

Calling `derived_object.normal_base_method()` really calls `BaseClass.normal_base_method`, but because `self` refers to `derived_object`, the `static_method` is chosen from `DerivedClass`.

Comment: Great example, thanks.
I tried to replace static method with instance method and outputs are the same.
So, if I understood it correct - there's no difference between behavior of static and instance methods in cases like this? Both are polymorphistic?

Comment: Yes, both are polymorphic. Python methods are implemented in a polymorphic way and neither the `@staticmethod` nor `@classmethod` decorators change that.